# Jquery loop while class does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to go though each page of the website and scrape data from each page. When a user clicks to new page button and once the page is loaded the value of current page number is set to `""`. So I am trying to use that as an indicator of when the page has finished loading

So I tried doing something like this, so that each loop waits until the page is fully loaded .

```
let totalNumberOfPages = -1;

$(".pagination .pg").each(function(data) {
  totalNumberOfPages++;
});

for (let i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfPages; i++) {
  $(".goto-page-input").val(i);
  $(".gotosubmit").click();

  // Wait until page loads
  while ($(".goto-page-input").val() != "") {
    // Loading
  }

  console.log(`Getting data of page ` + i);
}
```

The outer loop is to go though each page number buttons. However, this code does not work because it creates an infinite while loop. The while loop never ends because I beleive that it blocks the code and the code that is supposed to set the value of the page number to `""` never fires. I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: If the value isn't there, would it return empty, or undefined? Pretty sure .val() returns undefined if it doesn't get a value.

Comment: I tried it where there is no value and it retuns `""` so I used that

Comment: If you provide more context, we can help more. `while` may not even be the appropriate solution in some instances.

Comment: I am trying to scrape `https://www.ebay.com/myb/PurchaseHistory` website. Ebay only shows purchase history by page number and I cannot view all pages. Also a request is made to the server on each page change so there is a delay to get data after each page change. I do not want to hard code a setTimeOut function for like 5 seconds because that might not even be enough for slow internet or too much time when there are a lot of pages

Comment: So I am trying to change page wait until I finish scraping, and change page again and so on. I have already written a code to scrape the first page, I  am having difficult figuring out this probelm

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an event handler for the `change` event see example below. Do note the change event will be fired on loss of focus.

```js
(async () =>
{
  document.querySelector(".goto-page-input")
    .addEventListener("change", evt =>
    {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
      if (evt.target.value === "")
      {
        // LOGIC GOES HERE
        console.log('Logic is happening');
      }
    }, true);
})();
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Page" value="" class="goto-page-input" />
```

Comment: I was really hopeful about this but it looks like it cannot detect input field value changes. I looked around to see what other classes change and changed the querySelector class but it does not work either. I am trying to scrape `https://www.ebay.com/myb/PurchaseHistory` . For experimentation I tried to detect the `.cost-label` class change which definetly changes on each page change but the mutation listener does not fire

Comment: My mistake I misinterpreted the question and thought you were working on the node text not the input value. See updated answer on how to work with the change event handler. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
$(window).load(() => {
  console.log(“Getting data of page “ + i);
});
```

This will execute the callback function as soon as the window loads.

See docs: https://api.jquery.com/load/