# Is there a way to wait till a new page is loaded before executing another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spend a lot of time think about this and tried different things now. I want to scrape a webpage with multiple pages but the page does not reload on page change. Instead, some container data is changed on each changed page. The most difficult thing to do is know when to click the next page button.

Someone might think that this is pretty easy and I thought the same and started off by doing:

```js
$('.pagn a').each(function() {
  console.log(`Loop counter`)
  $(this).click()
  //Code to scrape the new page
})
```

Now, the loop runs 13 times but only one page is changed. This is because the pagination itself is inside the container that reloads so all other button presses are basically ignored.

To tackle this I needed some kind of a check that makes sure that the new content has loaded before proceeding but if I try to do something like:

```js
$('.pagn a').each(function() {
  console.log(`Loop counter`)
  while (someConditionToCheckIfPageLoaded) {

  }
  $(this).click()
  //Code to scrape the new page
})
```

This would be an infinite loop because JavaScript is single threaded and the code to change the condition never fires.

I also tried this which I now know is incorrect.

The indicator for page being loaded is if the button URL matches the page URL.

```js
$('.pagn a').each(function() {
  let visitedURL = [];
  if ($(this).attr('data-url')) {
    let button = $(this)
    buttonURL = "https://www.ebay.com/myb/PurchaseHistory#" + $(this).attr('data-url');
    (function wait() {
      button.click()

      if (buttonURL == location.href && !visitedURL.includes(button.html())) {
        console.log(button.html())
        button.click()
        visitedURL.push(button.html())
        console.log(buttonURL);
        console.log(location.href);
        //Scrape page
      } else {
        setInterval(wait, 5000);
      }
    })();
  }
})
```

This also only changes one page.

If someone has been able to scrape webpages with multiple pages with JavaScript please let me know how.

Edit1:

Also, I am not sure why this creates an infinite loop as well:

```
 let glbElements = []
    $('.pagn a').each(function() {
        glbElements.push($(this))
    })

    for(let i = 0 ; i<glbElements.length; i++){
        console.log(`Loop Counter`)
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(`Inside SetTimeout`) 
            glbElements[i].click()
            glbElements.splice(i,1)
        },2000)
    }
```

> Lopp Counter  *5 
>   Inside SetInterval  -- Keeps printing

Comment: once the page changes, javascript context is lost. you could persist things in one of the `*Storage` mechanisms

Comment: you need to take it out of a loop. make a global list, and call when ready; your timeout approach is generally fine for that, you just need to un-sequence it from firing all at once. i typically write a function called next() and one called done(). next is something like `item=list.pop(); if(item){do stuff; setTimeout(next,9); }else{done()}`...

Comment: Did you try to listen `readystatechange`?

Comment: @DanielA.White The page does not reload. Only some content changes

Comment: is this in the browser or nodejs?

Comment: @DanielA.White Browser

Comment: so what do you mean wait for another page to be loaded? in a frame?

Comment: @DanielA.White No. When I say another page, I just mean based on content. There is no page reload or iframe. It changes html of a container

Comment: please provide a more complete example.

Comment: I asked the question yesterday as well. I have been on this for a while. Would this be more helpful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240542/jquery-loop-while-class-does-not-exist

Comment: I will explain more if it does not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function to wait after a user clicks a button.
Like this:

```html
<a href='newpage.html'><button id='click'>Click!</button</a>
```

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
// code you want executed after page is loaded
}, 100);
});
```